# WScript.Shell CurrentDirectory returning the location of the calling app not current location

Tags: javascript, vbscript, activex, hta, wsh

I have two applications. The first one calls the second. The second one needs to know where it is on the local machine. But the `CurrentDirectory` instruction returns the location of the first application.

```
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var dirScript = objShell.CurrentDirectory;
```

How can I get the real location of the second application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first application knows where the second app is, it should be able to pass that value as a parameter.